# DEM coordinates do not align other data layers

Tags: remote-sensing

I recently downloaded Original Product Resolution (OPR) Digital Elevation Model (DEM) data for some analysis. The DEM do not align with any of the other data sets I have for the area. How can I rectify this problem?

Comment: Pretty sure this is going to be a GIS Stack Exchange question.  I haven't had great success getting response on similar topics there, but maybe you can [search there](https://gis.stackexchange.com) and find some input.  Personally, at least, GIS can be quite the challenge to work through issues :-/

Comment: Step 1: Tell people, which software you're working with.